# Calculating Normals 2d

Tags: java, math, vector, collision-detection, normalization

I'm trying to implement separating axis theorem to detect collisions between two polygons. I understand the concept of it, I'm just getting stuck on one part of it.
Basicially I need a line for each side of each polygon to project the polygons on to. 
So I have to use each vertice of each polygon to detect the edge of the shape and then create a line from that line. I've read loads of stuff online but everyone seems to be skipping over this part, maybe I'm just thinking to hard about it, but I'm getting confused.

I've been using this code, http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55, I've found online to help me, but I'm getting confused about the perp part.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < polygon.vertices.length; i++) {

    Vector p1 = polygon.vertices[i];
    Vector p2 = polygon.vertices[i + 1 == polygon.vertices.length ? 0 : i + 1];

    Vector edge = p1.subtract(p2);

    Vector normal = edge.perp();
    // the perp method is just (x, y) => (-y, x) or (y, -x)
    axes[i] = normal;
}
```

I know it has something to do with if the vertices being read clockwise or anti clockwise but I'm still not sure.

When I work the calculations down on paper the x an y of the normal seem to be way off?
If anyone has any experience with this it would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

Essentially What I want to do is find the axis perpendicular to the current edge

so if I've got (7,9) - (10,5) `Vector edge = (-3,4)` Do I then have to something like `(-Y, X)` to get this?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, but (-y, x) is the vector that you get by rotating (x, y) by 90 degrees anti-clockwise. It is therefore perpendicular (or "orthogonal") to (x, y).

Comment: Okay thanks, is that what people mean by normalize then, in the context of SAT?

Comment: In 2d, a "normal vector" is one that is perpendicular to a given object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry)). A normal vector is sometimes required to be "normalized", which means that is has the length 1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).

Answer (score 0):

A normal vector is not defined over 2 dimensional spaces.
It is generally applied to 3 dimensional spaces. If you have two vector3s the normal to the surface they represent is their cross product. so for a = [x1, y1, z1], and b = [x2, y2, z2] the normal vector is a X b, the   [Cross Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product/)  of a and b.

Comment: It needs to be 2d though

Comment: Well, you can't have a normal vector in 2d. Do you mean a unit vector?

Comment: Yes maybe, what I've read is that I need to  'calculate the normals' of the edge.

Comment: I don't know. you need 2 edges to calculate a normal to a polygon but that's in 3d. The link you posted contains several examples in 3d as well. But it deals in points that is vertices, not in Xs and Ys. In other words, in any number of dimensions a line-segment is still defined by 2 points. but the arity (number of components) of the points goes up.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never studied the separating axis theorem.